# str_replace css meta tag?

Tags: filters, hooks

I'm trying to modify the css meta tag and make use of a CDN url - and other things.

What I have tried (as a quick test) is :

```
function change_stylesheet_loc($uri)
{
    $uri = str_replace('example.com', 'cdn.example.com', $uri);
    return $uri;
}
add_filter('stylesheet_uri', 'change_stylesheet_loc', 20000);
```

I've also tried :

```
add_filter('the_content', 'change_stylesheet_loc', 20000);
```

Nothing I'm doing is working. How can I modify the css meta tag data?

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that, use `wp_enqueu_style` with `wp_register_style` and `wp_deregister_style`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style

Also a `$priority` of 20k..why would you pick such an arbitrary number.